# how to make "git log commit..commit.." display ONLY commits from given branch

Tags: git

I'm writing an "update" hook to inform issue-tracker about pushed commits

update hooks gets arguments as follows:

"ref" "oldrev" "newrev" (where oldrev and newrev are commit hashes, and ref is a ref name, i.e. "branch")

what is very annoying (and basically destroys whe whole point), is that using simply "git log oldrev..newrev" (for the case when ref already exists in refs/heads) enumerates all the commits done in other branches as well, if those branches were merged to "ref".

how can I ask git to display ONLY those commits, that are reachable ONLY from ref ?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to hide the branches merged to "ref" `git log --first-parent` might be enough.

If on the other hand "ref" is not the main branch and you're trying to skim off the commits before its starting point, that seems to be pretty much an unsolved problem

Comment: (the command I use is "git log --oneline --first-parent rev1..rev2". It works perfectly on working repo, even when the branch in question is not current. have yet to check how will it perform on bare repo)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
--no-merges
Do not print commits with more than one parent. This is exactly the same as --max-parents=1.
```

from documentation on [git-log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Comment: It indeed removes "merges", but not regular commits, done on the "other" branch[es]. What I want is to display ONLY commits belonging ONLY to a branch being pushed (because the other commits were already on repo)